# Error - Why am I receiving an syntax error warning when initialising an object

Tags: typescript

I'm new to type script and I'm learning it by trying to convert javascript files into type script.

I have come to a situation where I'm receiving an error warning at the colon symbol of an object:

```
[context!.label] **:** message.replace(/['"]/g, "")
```

JoiError definition is as following code:

```
private initializeJoiError = (error: Joi.ValidationError) => {
  this._JoiError = {
       status: "failed",
       validationErrors: {
            details: _.map(error.details, ({message, context}) => {
            [context!.label] : message.replace(/['"]/g, "")
           })
       }
  }
}

Can someone explain me why I'm receiving this error and how to fix it?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because TypeScript interprets the innermost part of your nested function as a function body wrapped in a `{ ... }` block.

Try returning an explicit object from that function instead:

```js
private initializeJoiError = (error: Joi.ValidationError) => {
  this._JoiError = {
    status: "failed",
    validationErrors: {
      details: _.map(error.details, ({message, context}) => {
        return {[context!.label] : message.replace(/['"]/g, "")}
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and now I'm receiving the error warning: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464) at [context!.label]. Any idea??

Comment: You probably need to say that your `context` variable needs to have a typing as well. Something like: `({message, context} : {message: string, context: { label: string }})` might work.

Comment: Thnx @Frost, it worked!